# Rally SDK 1.x - Getting preferences to scope up/down projects

Tags: javascript, preferences, rally

I've been working on customizing the AgileEVM app using sdk 1.32 and I've been using preferences to store various values that users will set (multiple billable rates, non-full time resources, etc..). Here is how I'm creating the preferences:

```
_rallyDataSource.create("preference",
{
    Name: 'BillableRate',
    Project: '/project/__PROJECT_OID__',
    Value: 0
}, function(results) { isTeamLevel = results; } );
```

The workspace is structured where the parent project has multiple tracks and those tracks have multiple teams. I want the app to calculate the appropriate EVM data on every level of the project hierarchy. I'm running into an issue where I can't retrieve the preferences of the current project as well as all of its child projects. **PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN** is set to true. It seems like preferences are handled differently than stories/tasks/etc..

Here is how I'm getting the preference(s):

```
var queryConf = {type: 'Preference',
                 key :'billableRate',
                 query:'(Project = "/project/__PROJECT_OID__")',
                 fetch:true};

_rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConf, preferencesRetrievedCallback);
```

If I include the project oid in the query, I only get preferences associated with that project, none of the child projects. If I remove the project oid from the query, it returns every preference, regardless of hierarchy.

I also tried to accomplish this using CreateAppPreference and GetAppPreferences, but it appeared to exhibit the same behavior.

My question is, am I doing something wrong here? If not, and this is the intended functionality, then how do I best store these variables so that they roll up properly at every level of the project structure?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Preference WSAPI endpoint is a bit unique in that it doesn't use any workspace or project scoping information passed in the url except for explicit queries like you have above:

```
 (Project = /project/12345)
```

You could use the **PROJECT_OIDS_IN_SCOPE** [hangman variable](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/Hangman-variables) and construct a large OR'd query, although if you have a lot of projects in scope the request may fail because it gets too large...

```
var queries = [];
var projectOids = '__PROJECT_OIDS_IN_SCOPE__'.split(',');
rally.forEach(projectOids, function(projectOid) {
    queries.push('Project = /project/' + projectOid);
});
var query = rally.sdk.util.Query.or(queries);
```

Otherwise you could just make a new preference request for each project in scope much like you are doing for the current project.

Another option would be to save the pref as a workspace pref instead and have the value be a json object with keys being project oids and values being the value...

Comment: Knowing that there won't be a large number of projects in scope, I went with your first solution. Worked perfectly. Thanks for the quick and thorough answer!!